# Neo4j Connector for java

Tags: java, database, neo4j

Is there a connector for the Neo4J server running at localhost:7474 that I can use in java? What I am looking for is something like 'JDBC' for MySQL where I can execute queries and updates as strings rather than using an embedded database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [JDBC driver for Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/tools/jdbc). You execute Cypher queries using this driver. Cypher is to Neo4j as SQL is to RDBMS.